# Creating and sorting a dynamic table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub where i want to create a table so that i can sort it afterwards (one of the columns must be in descending order).

The sub works when i have the workbook open and on the correct worksheet.

When i try to run the code without having to look at the worksheet at the same time, the following problem pops up:

"Method 'Range' of object_global' failed"

"Can't execute code in break mode"

This is what my sub looks like. The row is static but the column length changes from time to time.

```
Sub create_the_table_investeringsforeninger()
' Best used when row length is static

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

'Refresh UsedRange
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).UsedRange

Lrow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sht.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=sht.Range("A2:F2" & Lrow)).Name = "Investeringsforeninger"

'Sort Range "Investeringsforeninger"
Range("investeringsforeninger").Sort Key1:=Range("F2"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

The whole of my code is supposed to run without me having to open the document first (for this i am using a vbs document).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing references to your Worksheet, therefore it only works when it is the active sheet.  I deleted your `UsedRange` line as it does nothing.

```
Sub create_the_table_investeringsforeninger()
' Best used when row length is static

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

Lrow = sht.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
sht.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=sht.Range("A2:F2" & Lrow)).Name = "Investeringsforeninger"

'Sort Range "Investeringsforeninger"
sht.Range("investeringsforeninger").Sort Key1:=sht.Range("F2"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```